# How do I provide feedback to the developers of COS?

Tags: google-container-os

The links under [Resources/Accessing and Contributing to Source](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/resources/sources) seems to only link to the Chromium OS and not the `Container-Optimized OS`.

#### The actual feedback

I noticed that the "cpu MHz" entry under `/proc/cpuinfo` on `cos-dev` is `0`, compared to `cos-stable` which is `2600.000`.

While I realise that `dev` obviously means "under development", I haven't been able to find an issue tracker on the project, and it's causing my `docker build` to fail, because the "cpu mhz" information isn't propagated properly to the container, so a process that requires the information breaks.

This wasn't a problem when I was running with `cos-stable`, but I needed `v17.07+` of Docker, and `cos-stable` runs `v17.03`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this!
As of now we don't have public issue tracker,you can reach us at any of mentioned way listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/resources/support-policy).

I have not been able to reproduce this on latest COS image which is "cos-dev-70-11021-11-0", you could retry with latest. 
Here is the command/output I've tried with instance created from latest cos-dev image:

```
sawlani@cos-70 ~ $ cat /etc/lsb-release | grep BUILDER_PATH
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILDER_PATH=lakitu-release/R70-11021.11.0
sawlani@cos-70 ~ $ docker run --rm -it ubuntu cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"
cpu MHz     : 2598.945
sawlani@cos-70 ~ $
```